# How do you create an operator overload on a base class such that all derived classes will use it without calling the derived class methods

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class called ISignalFilter and I want to create derived classes such that all the derived classes can use an operator overload * to combine into another derived class called ProductFilter.

The problem is, product filter stores the base class and calls the base class method filtered_value. I want the ProductClass to call the derived class method filtered_value. How would I do this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <typename T>
class ISignalFilter;

template <typename F>
class ProductFilter;

template <typename T>
class ISignalFilter {
   public:
    virtual T filtered_value(const T& value) {
        (void)value;
        std::cout<<"Error this should not be called."<<std::endl;
        // BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "Base case usage of method not allowed";
        std::abort();
    };
    virtual ProductFilter<T> operator*(ISignalFilter<T>& other) {
        return ProductFilter<T>(*this, other);
    }
};

template <typename F>
class ProductFilter : public ISignalFilter<F> {
   public:
    ProductFilter(const ISignalFilter<F>& a, const ISignalFilter<F>& b) {
        a_ = a;
        b_ = b;
    }

    F filtered_value(const F& value) override {
        return b_.filtered_value(a_.filtered_value(value));
    }
    ISignalFilter<F> a_;
    ISignalFilter<F> b_;
};

template <typename T>
class IdentityFilter : public ISignalFilter<T> {
   public:
    IdentityFilter() {}
    T filtered_value(const T& value) override { return value; }
};

int main() {
    auto filter1 = IdentityFilter<int>();
    auto filter2 = filter1 * filter1;
    std::cout<<filter2.filtered_value(1)<<std::endl; //should output one. 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You see `ISignalFilter<T> a_;` and `ISignalFilter<T> b_;`? This means the ProductFilter has two ISignalFilters inside it. Not pointers to ISignalFilters that exist somewhere else, but actual ISignalFilters. Which means the type is exactly ISignalFilter and not some derived class of it.

Comment: @user253751 oooh so I should store and pass pointers instead?

Comment: also it doesn't need to be inside base class, imho it actually should not in this case.

Comment: @appleapple why? I want to derive multiple classes from the base class that automatically impliment the * operator by me only implementing filtered_value.

Comment: @BrianYeh there is no (much) difference put it inside or outside, and it's generally recommended to put it as non-member.

Answer (score 0):

Let's play with non-template classes to **resolve your title question**.
My suggestion is to use different named methods:

```
class Base
{
  public:
  bool operator==(const Base& other) const
  {
    return equal_to(other);
  }

  protected:
      virtual bool equal_to(const Base& other) const = 0;
};
```

In the above code fragment, the `operator==` is redirected to call a method, `equal_to` which is tagged so that child classes must implement it.

Whether derived classes use the `operator==` or call `equal_to` is up to the coder.

*Note: for best results, overloading `operator==` should be in each derived class.  See also "object slicing".*

Comment: I actually don't want this. I want derived classes to only have to implement filtered_value. Then a universal definition should operate correctly by only using the derived filtered_value methods.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem, as @user253751 said in comment, is you need to store reference/pointer for *dynamic* polymorphism to work.

---

there are some other thing to change

- mark the method `const` (or accept non-`const` for `ProductFilter` constructor)
- the operator can be defined outside of `ISignalFilter`, and as it's actually a functionality of `ProductFilter`, it's reasonable to do it.
- use pure virtual function (`=0`) to catch error at compile time (and your code actually would shows error because you cannot create instance of `ISignalFilter<T>`)
- you probably also want to return `const T&` for filtered_value

---

the final code

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ISignalFilter {
    virtual T filtered_value(const T& value) const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct ProductFilter : ISignalFilter<T> {
    ProductFilter(const ISignalFilter<T>& a, const ISignalFilter<T>& b)
      :a(a),b(b){}

    T filtered_value(const T& value) const override {
        return b.filtered_value(a.filtered_value(value));
    }
    const ISignalFilter<T> &a, &b;
};

template<typename T>
ProductFilter<T> operator*(const ISignalFilter<T>& a, const ISignalFilter<T>& b) {
    return ProductFilter<T>(a,b);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oxxKx9z4z

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. I want to create ancestors for ISIgnalFilter such that they all automatically work with the * operator. This is similar to behavior of type classes in haskell. All derived classes do not have to impliment the * operator but they should work.

Comment: @BrianYeh yes it's what the code did. `IdentityFilter` works as intended if you follow the link.

Comment: @BrianYeh note that the `operator*` is for `ISignalFilter`, the base class.